# Google Charts: How to add class to column of table?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, google-visualization

I have created table with Google Chart API and I would like to align text in one of the columns to the right. I have been looking for solution to include bootstrap "text-right" class to this s but didnt find a lot of sources how to do that.

So after sorting it, I thought to share how to do that :)

Answer (score 4):

This is very simple. You need to use setColumnProperty() method of google.visualization.DataTable() object.

```
var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
data.addColumn('string', 'First name');
data.addColumn('string', 'Last name');
data.addColumn('string', 'Address');

// add rows here like: data.addRow(['a', 'b', 'c']);

data.setColumnProperty(2, 'className', 'text-right');
```

First number is referring to which column is that. In my example First name is 0, Last name is 1, and Address is 2. So I'm adding class named 'text-right' to all s in the third column (Address).

Answer (score 0):

you can also add within the column definition...

```
data.addColumn({type: 'string', label: 'Address', p: {className: 'text-right'}});
```